# GNUplot: Missing interactive terminals

Tags: qt, plot, graph, terminal, gnuplot

I am a gnuplot newbie. As I run gnuplot in the terminal, I get

```
$gnuplot
    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 2    last modified 2017-11-15 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2017
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'unknown'
```

So, I did

```
gnuplot> set term

Available terminal types:
           canvas  HTML Canvas object
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
          domterm  DomTerm terminal emulator with embedded SVG
             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
            eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
              emf  Enhanced Metafile format
            emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
              fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
              gif  GIF images using libgd and TrueType fonts
             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
             jpeg  JPEG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
            latex  LaTeX picture environment
              lua  Lua generic terminal driver
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
              png  PNG images using libgd and TrueType fonts
       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
          pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
            pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
         pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
              qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)
          sixelgd  sixel using libgd and TrueType fonts
              svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics
          tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
          tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
          texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
             tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]
             tikz  TeX TikZ graphics macros via the lua script driver
         tkcanvas  Tk canvas widget
             tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials
          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
            vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
            xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

At my surprise there is no `wxt` or `qt`.

I manage to produce plots by saving them on a file such as for example

```
set term png
set out "test.png"
plot sin(x)
```

but I fail to get the plot open in a new terminal window. In `R` I can just do

```
$r
> plot(1:10)
```

and I get the plot opening up in a new terminal window.

**How can I have my plot showing up directly on a new terminal window?**

---

I am on

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.13.2
BuildVersion:   17C88
```

My Xcode version is

```
Xcode 9.2
Build version 9C40b
```

Comment: How did you install gnuplot on your Mac? You seem to be missing the interactive terminals like qt, wxt, or x11.

Comment: @user8153 With homebrew. `brew install gnupot`

Comment: `brew install gnuplot --with-qt`, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32421713/2604213

Comment: @Christoph Thanks I just figured it out. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
brew uninstall gnuplot
brew uninstall aquaterm
brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt
```

solved my problem