# Make toolbar visible in gnuplot on Mac

Tags: macos, gnuplot, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I followed this link [Install gnuplot 5.0.1 on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32421713/install-gnuplot-5-0-1-on-osx) to install gnuplot on MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 via

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/aquaterm
brew install gnuplot --with-aquaterm --with-qt
```

However, when I do a plot with the just installed gnuplot, it does not show any tool/menubar in the plot window, just the plot itself. How can I make this visible?

[image]

There used to be a toolbar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that is was related to the aquaterm, using just qt, gives the expected toolbar.